# task ':app:mergeDebugResources' AaptException: Failed to crunch file

Tags: android

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
Error: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: Failed to crunch file C:\Users\SONY\Desktop\Project tango\zip folder Project Tango\tango-examples-java-master\Solution\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.4.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png into C:\Users\SONY\Desktop\Project tango\zip folder Project Tango\tango-examples-java-master\Solution\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png
```

Answer (score 0):

file crunching fails due to improper image or media files make sure all your image name are in small letters without space or special characters except '_'.
also proper format of image is selected e.g if u rename a jpg image to png without converting it wont work.remove the image which u inserted rebuild your project i hope it works for you

Comment: try to be more specific to the answer. The image inside name inside the error log is android built file